# Add Firebase to Android app

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to install Firebase to my Android app, but it's seems like I'm doing something wrong. I have done exactly the same what I saw in this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=hu#available_libraries).

But when I put this `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'` into my project, I'm getting this error message:

```
Could not fint support-annotations.jar.....
```

The tutorial says something about this error:

```
Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager˛
```

The problem with this is that I have the latest version of Google Repository. And I cannot update it because there is no update available in SDK Manager.

Do you have you any idea what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Extras section of the Android SDK Manager, make sure the Android Support Library (v23.2.1) and Android Repository (v38) are installed and up to date.

The Support Annotation Library is [described here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html).

The tutorial tip referring to the Google Repository applies when the "Could not find" error is for one of the Firebase libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update android studio and gradle plugins. After that everything works fine.